# Angular JS Method are not defined with Wcf Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wcf

I am consuming Wcf Service in Angular Js Application . My Wcf Service is working and I am trying to display List of User Record from Sql Database . When I run the
application its giving me following errors ...

```
 angular.js:14642 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAllStudent' of undefined
    at GetAllRecords (Registration.js:13)
```

Here is My Script.js file code ...

```
/// <reference path="../angular.min.js" />  



var app = angular.module("WebClientModule", [])

    .controller('Web_Client_Controller', ["$scope", 'myService', function ($scope, myService, CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService) {

        $scope.OperType = 1;
        GetAllRecords();
        //To Get All Records  
        function GetAllRecords() {
            var promiseGet = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.getAllStudent();
            promiseGet.then(function (pl) { $scope.User = pl.data },
                function (errorPl) {
                    $log.error('Some Error in Getting Records.', errorPl);
                });
        }
        //1 Mean New Entry  

        //To Clear all input controls.  
        function ClearModels() {
            $scope.OperType = 1;
            $scope.Username = "";
            $scope.Password = "";
            $scopr.Email = "";

        }


        $scope.createuser = function () {
            var User = {
                Username: $scope.Username,
                Password: $scope.Password,
                Email: $scope.Email

            };
            if ($scope.OperType === 1) {
                var promisePost = myService.post(User);
                promisePost.then(function (pl) {
                    $scope.User_Id = pl.data.User_Id;
                    window.location.href = "/Login/Index";

                    ClearModels();
                }, function (err) {
                    $scope.msg = "Password Incorrect !";
                    console.log("Some error Occured" + err);
                });
            }
        }
    }]);

app.service("myService", function ($http) {
    //Create new record  
    this.post = function (User) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/Register",
            data: JSON.stringify(User)
        });
        return request;

        this.getAllStudent = function () {
            return $http.get("http://localhost:56766/StudentService.svc/GetAllStudent");
        }
    }


})
```

Here is HTML Code..

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<html data-ng-app="WebClientModule">
<head title="ASAS">
    <title></title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/RegistrationScript/Registration.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <table id="tblContainer" data-ng-controller="Web_Client_Controller">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="border: solid 2px Green; padding: 5px;">
                    <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
                        <th></th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Password</th>
                        <th>Emial</th>

                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody data-ng-repeat="user in Users">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span>{{user.User_Id}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{user.Username}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{user.Password}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{user.Email}}</span></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" id="Edit" value="Edit" data-ng-click="get(user)" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" id="Delete" value="Delete" data-ng-click="delete(user)" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="color: red;">{{Message}}</div>
                <table style="border: solid 4px Red; padding: 2px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>User ID</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="User_Id" readonly="readonly" data-ng-model="User_Id" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Username</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="username" data-ng-model="Username" required="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Password</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" id="password" required data-ng-model="Password" require="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Email</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="email" id="email" required data-ng-model="Email" require="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" id="Createuser" value="Submit" data-ng-click="createuser()" />
                            <input type="button" id="Clear" value="Clear" data-ng-click="Clear()" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<script src="~/RegistrationScript/Registration.js"></script>
```

Here is the screen shot when I run the application.

[image: Click here to see the result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service should looks like:

```
app.service("myService", function ($http) {
    //Create new record  
    this.post = function (User) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/Register",
            data: JSON.stringify(User)
        });
        return request;

    };
    this.getAllStudent = function () {
            return $http.get("http://localhost:56766/StudentService.svc/GetAllStudent");
        }

})
```

`this.getAllStudent` should be outside of `this.post` function.

and in controller:

```
var promiseGet = myService.getAllStudent();
```

Comment: I can access method when I run the wcf service but in Angular Js when I lunch the developer tools .its is showing   
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED..

Comment: I have some record in database which should display when the website is first loaded